# Router User Interface is very slow and freezes sometimes

Tags: router

I have a problem with my router which sometimes drops the internet connections and freezes. When the internet connection drops I go to the Router web interface and it takes up to 20 seconds to load. This is not normal as this kind of connection should be instantaneous.I am not using any VPN or other kind of connection. So since of this delay I suppose the router froze for a little bit. Right? 
I access the router through the provided IP address and I am using my laptop which is 6 meters away from the router. My connections are all Wifi. I don't have a desktop PC so wired connections is not an option. Don't want to carry the laptop from room to room to check what is wrong with the internet connection.

I have the Netgear N600 and replaced it with Tp-link TL-WR940N and still the same problem.

However, sometimes the UI of the TP-link is very fast like opening a folder. But for the Netgear it was always slow. But it never froze or at least didn't recognize it.

Both had the latest firmware.

Comment: Try to factory reset the router (will require redoing all settings). Does the router over-heat? Is there available a firmware update?

Comment: Tried it and also checked for latest firmware. Router is up to date and still freezes sometimes.

Comment: The problem seems to be with your computer. Try to boot in Safe Mode With Network to check if it's caused by some installed product. Security and antivirus products are prime candidates.

Comment: Tried to access UI from phone and same problem. Yesterday I had to replace the router with Netgear N600. The  TP-link router has now constant freeze and I have to  plug it out and in every few minutes. As for overheating:No I can't feel any heat from the router.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that Internet over WiFi is fast enough but only the router's interface is slow, and that happened with two different routers? What happens when booting in Safe Mode With Network? Try also to disable your firewall temporarily.

Comment: Yes the internet connection itself is very fast. 2Mbps . Didn't use safe mode because this also happens when I try to access the router from mobile phone (iPhone to be specific)

Comment: It doesn't depend on device or software on it. Web UI IS extremely slow. It takes about 20-30 minutes to do all settings. Damn it, I could write all that "interface" faster than it loads.